# Local Region recognition while the app isn't running in iOs

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, location, core-location

I'm developing a simple application that when i press one button, creates a Local Region. Till this is all ok, the app creates Region and notify correctly when i enter in this, even if my app is in background. Now, i think that my question is so tricky. Can i create an app that while it's running creates a local region, but even when it's NOT running notify that we are entered in the region created before? I want to know if there is a method that allow me to monitoring significant location changes, even when the app is closed. And if this method recognize (with the app still closed) that i'm entered in a Local Region, starts to uploading my location (i don't know, with a costant interval or something).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a region and your app will get notified via the UIApplication's Launch Options.  This will launch you app and you can handle the event then.  There will be some limits what you can do when the app is still in the background.

This article from Apple should be helpful:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/monitoring_the_user_s_proximity_to_geographic_regions

Edit: You also must enable `Location updates` for Background Modes in the Capabilities.

Comment: thank you! In this article is written that the Regions are monitored by the system. So the system is able to monitor the Region also with the app closed. But how can i implement that? i have implemented the function createRegion so when it is called, it creates a Region, stop updating the location and start monitoring region. I've made this because i want to start updating location again only when i enter in the Region. But the monitoring region's function works only if the app is running or in background. I dont know how to make that function works when the app is not running!

Comment: I don't quite understand how you implemented it.  The system is the only thing that has access to the GPS chip, which in turn notifies the apps 'listening' to the location changes.  When you create a region, you are telling the system you are interested in the GPS changes around that region.  Could you update your post with the code how you create your region?

Comment: Also, when you enter a region, and the app is terminated, the system will wake your app via the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in your appDelegate.  `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` is the specific option key passed to that method.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationlaunchoptionslocationkey?language=objc

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not mean I implemented it by myself. 
I meant that I use that function that way. forgive my mistake! I'll update the code as soon as possible! Thank you!